# How to programmatically create a UISlider like that of Apple Music in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking to create a UISlider like the one below: 
[image]

I've seen code like the following to change the image, but ideally I'd like to forgo using an image and create a basic downward line programmatically.

```
var thumbImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "yourImage")!
var size = CGSizeMake( thumbImage.size.width * ratio, thumbImage.size.height * ratio )
self.setThumbImage( self.imageWithImage(thumbImage, scaledToSize: size), forState: UIControlState.Normal )
```

Comment: Other than the two volume icons at each end, that's a standard `UISlider`. Your question isn't really clear. What are you actually having trouble with trying to make your slider?

Comment: BTW - please crop your image. No need to post a full screenshot just to show a slider.

Comment: Apologies, I'll try to be more verbose - I'm trying to recreate the red thumb controller - without using an image. The red line going vertically down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UISlider is designed to use an image for the "thumb" control. If you want to draw the thumb control programmatically you will need to create your own control. A slider isn't that complicated. It would be fairly straightforward. (But it would be a heck of a lot easier to just use the standard slider control with a red line as the thumb image.)

Comment: Yep I suppose it is the way that it was designed, thanks.